# When i make 2 counts for the same column and group them by a third in sql it gives me an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried counting and grouping data from 1 column (track id) for when its value is 0, and when it is different than 0, the grouping being done for another column, namely radioid in my code. However, Microsoft Visual studio gives me an error, which i can't understand. Any helpers

```
SELECT RadioID,
(SELECT COUNT (TrackID) FROM tblZampMediaLogItem WHERE TrackID!=0) AS NajdeniPesni,
(SELECT COUNT (TrackID) FROM tblZampMediaLogItem WHERE TrackID=0) AS Nenajdenipesni
Group BY RadioID;
```

error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid column name 'RadioID'.
>
> Msg207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'RadioID'.

Why can't it recognise radioid? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer query does not have a from clause, therefore mssql server cannot recognise from where the radioid field comes from. Assuming that radioid field is in the same table as you used in the subquery, I would rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT RadioID,
SUM(CASE WHEN TrackID !=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NajdeniPesni,
SUM(CASE WHEN TrackID =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nenajdenipesni
FROM tblZampMediaLogItem
Group BY RadioID;
```

This way you do not have to run 3 queries, just one.

Comment: You sire are a genius! Thank you
I'm new to sql so this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your missing `FROM DatabaseName` .. Try this..

```
SELECT RadioID,
(SELECT COUNT (TrackID) FROM tblZampMediaLogItem WHERE TrackID!=0) AS NajdeniPesni,
(SELECT COUNT (TrackID) FROM tblZampMediaLogItem WHERE TrackID=0) AS Nenajdenipesni
FROM tblZampMediaLogItem Group BY RadioID;
```

Comment: This solution would result in running 3 queries against the same table.

Comment: @Shadow , Yup i know :) .. my only concern is to fix the problem itself and not optimizing the query :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the FROM clause: it doesn't which is the referred table!